# Rails ActiveRecord get value from column, or from association's default if nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm sure this has been answered, but my searching is failing me.

I have two models:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :family
    # has column "last_name"
end

class Family < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :people
    # has column "last_name"
end
```

I would like `Person.take.last_name` to:

- If the Person has a `last_name` that is not nil, return that
- If the Person has a Family, return that family's `last_name`
- Otherwise, return nil.

I could do something like

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :family
    # has column "last_name"

    def last_name_lookup
        last_name || family&.last_name || nil
    end
end
```

But was wondering if there is a built-in rails way to do this, or if it's considered improper to mask a column's true value.

Comment: I'd probably go with your `last_name_lookup` approach (or an equivalent in a decorator, view model, helper, ...). Overriding `last_name` itself could lead to the `last_name` column getting changed to the family last name when you're not expecting it.

Comment: Can you fill the column `Person#last_name` with `Family#last_name` at creation? If so, you can avoid to run this at runtime and performing a N+1 query with family association. If you iterate over persons and forgot to include family on your fetch query, this will lead into N+1 query. Try to resolve on creation and normalize your base

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks, interesting. Could you elaborate on how overriding could lead to the column getting changed when not expected?

Comment: If you override `Person#last_name`, then put a Person in an editing form and that Person didn't have a `last_name`, the form would end up with the family last name in the `last_name` field. Then the form goes back to the server with the family's last name and the person ends up with a `last_name`.

Comment: Thanks--good to know

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a Rails built-in way. But you can do

```rb
# in person.rb

def last_name # yes, overrides the built-in getter
  read_attribute(:last_name) || family&.last_name # will be nil if both last_names are nil
end
```